# Error, when trying to change state with useState - Identifier expected. 'true' is a reserved word that cannot be used here.ts(1359)

Tags: reactjs

I have been working with React for already 1 month and I am also using the hook `useState()`. But today I experienced such a weird error, which says, that I can't use "true" as a `setState` value. I use this hook very often, but this is the first time when nothing happens. The error, which is showing, is following:

> Identifier expected. 'true' is a reserved word that cannot be used here.ts(1359)

It shows up, when I write `setLoading(true)` inside `fetchTours` function and the true is not accepted.

This is my code -

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Loading from './Loading'
import Tours from './Tours'

const url = 'https://course-api.com/react-tours-project'
function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [tours, setTours] = useState([])

  const fetchTours = async () = {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(url);

  }

  if(loading){
    return (
      <main>
        <Loading />
      </main>
    );
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <Tours />
    </main>
  )
}

export default App
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? Or was it due to the missing arrow? I am seeing a similar error and the only way to fix it is by declaring a variable with value `false` and passing that as parameter... not very nice :/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a syntax error, need a fat arrow. Like this:

```js
const fetchTours = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(url);

  }
```